# How to build a two-colum HTML table with XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I have an xml document that contains a list of titles. I need to loop through the title and build a two-column table dynamically.

### XML Document

```
<documents>
    <titles>
        <title>One</title>
        <title>two</title>
        <title>three</title>
        <title>four</title>
        <title>five</title>
        <title>six</title>
        <title>eight</title>
    </titles>
</documents>
```

XSLT
I know it's wrong and I am not that good with XSLT loops.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>
<xsl:variable name="newline"><xsl:text>
</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
        <html>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
            <head>
                <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                <xsl:comment> Sitemap 1.0 </xsl:comment>
                <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
            </head>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
            </body>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
        </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="titles">
         <table>
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>hello</th>
                     <th>hello2</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="title">

                        <tr>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </tr>

                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
         </table>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Actual Result

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

      <!-- Sitemap 1.0 -->

   </head>

   <body>
      <documents>

         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>hello</th>
                  <th>hello2</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>One</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>two</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>three</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>four</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>five</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>six</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>eight</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>

      </documents>

   </body>

</html>
```

### Expected Result

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

      <!-- Sitemap 1.0 -->

   </head>

   <body>
      <documents>

         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>hello</th>
                  <th>hello2</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>One</td>
                  <td>two</td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                  <td>three</td>
                   <td>four</td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                  <td>five</td>
                  <td>six</td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                  <td>eight</td>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>

      </documents>

   </body>

</html>
```

How can I build a two-column table when the selection is always a single/the same node()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your for-loop to this

```
<xsl:for-each select="title[position() mod 2 = 1]">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::title[1]"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It selects every second element and then outputs also the following title element.